# php curl post call for uploading image with other attributes

Tags: php, api

I am using a basic PHP curl to post data to [iNaturalist API call](http://www.inaturalist.org/pages/api+reference#post-observation_photos) but I am getting internal server error.

My HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <form action="imageuploaddir.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">

    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

and my imageuploaddir.php code is

```
 <?php
$authorization = "Authorization: Bearer ###somekey;

$file=$_FILES["fileToUpload"];

$postfields = array('file' =>'@'.$file,'observation_photo[observation_id]'=> 4230809);
var_dump($postfields);
$ch =curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.inaturalist.org/observation_photos");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postfields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data",
  $authorization
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$err = curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}

?>




 $postfields = array('file' =>'@'.$file,'observation_photo[observation_id]'=> 4230809);
```

When I give a post in this format I get an error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the postfields array and set CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD to false to successfully post image and other attribute to API.

```
$postfields =  array(
      'file' =>
          '@'            . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']
          . ';filename=' . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']
          . ';type='     . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['type']
    ,'observation_photo[observation_id]'=>4230809);
```

I also set CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD to false   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD,false);